# Core Animation Unwanted Text Sharpening

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nstextfield

Whenever I add a layer for Core Animation either from the nib or programatically, the NSTextFields (labels) in my interface get messed up. Here's a screenshot from Apple's *BasicCocoaAnimations* example. (Look at the text fields on the left, somehow they're drawn sharper than normal)[alt text http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/4162/picture5lz.png](http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/4162/picture5lz.png)

Note that if I add a layer in IB then it also gets messed up in IB itself before I even run my app. This happens on my 10.5.8 PowerPC Mac.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread: [Text Not Anti-Aliased Inside NSView?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=613575) for some discussion and possible resolution.